# What is the universal covering space of the projective line $\mathbb{RP}^1$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, projective-geometry, covering-spaces, projective-space

I´m thinking about universal covering spaces. I´ve seen a lot of examples and authors ever say "the sphere $S^n$ is the universal covering space of the $n$-dimensional projective space $\mathbb{R}P^n$ for $n \geq 1$.

So my question is: and what about the real projective line $\mathbb{R}P^1$? Has it universal covering space?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\mathbb{R}P^1$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^1$. To see this, first note that more generaly $\mathbb{R}P^n\simeq\mathbb{S}^n/_{\pm id}$ and in the case $n=1$ you have $ \mathbb{S}^1/_{\pm id}\simeq \mathbb{S}^1$ (just factorize the map $z\mapsto z^2$).

From here you can conclude.

Comment: Sure! I had the homeomorphism but I missed it! Lol.    Thanks!  :D

Answer (score 5):

The real projective line is just a circle, so the universal covering space is the real line.

Comment: I don´t agree. Even it´s not a circumference. It´s a quotient of a circumference, yeah?

Comment: @user A cheap way to see it is that the unique closed one dimensional manifold is a circle. There's nothing else it can be.

Comment: Important to note is that it isn’t the universal cover.

Comment: What I mean is that $S^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}P^1$ is a covering space, but not a universal one.

Comment: @Connor I agree. Note my answer says the real line is the universal cover.